# Use OAuthWebSecurity API In Custom Membersip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership

I want use the OAuthWebSecurity API in a custom membersip and not the SimpleMembership.
my project is ASP.NET MVC 4.

Link found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158425%28v=vs.111%29)

My question: How i can do this work?

Comment: I suggest you  read 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Comment: i read this article but not include my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a few things in place.

First you need your Custom membership provider to inherit from **WebMatrix.WebData.ExtendedMembershipProvider**

This has a whole bunch of extra methods for dealing with OAuth.